# Is it possible to run a vlookup without opening the spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I have a spreadsheet that shows weekly sales data. There are 52 columns to represent 52 weeks. Each weekly column is pointing to a spreadsheet containing the corresponding weekly data. E.g. wk1 column points to wk1.xls, wk2 column points to wk2.xls and so forth.

These columns grab data via vlookups.

There are vlookups pointing to a non-existing spreadsheet because we are not yet up to that week yet. However, once that spreadsheet exists, the vlookup will immediately grab the data and populate the column. Great.

The vlookups will not initiate the grabbing of data unless you open the spreadsheet. **Is it possible to trigger/run/activate vlookups without opening a spreadsheet?**

Bearing in mind, i have macros as well. I plan to trigger these macros when certain cell ranges change/update i.e. when the vlookups have updated themselves.

**Edit for KrisB---**

See below for the code that I use to copy and paste a whole workbook into another. How do I adjust the code to copy and paste a specified range of cells into another spreadsheet?

```
Sub update_BSL_BRANCHSTOCK_WHOUSESTOCK_ONORDER()
Dim n As Long
Const csFOLDER_PATH As String = "...\OTC\2016\Reports Sent\"

For n = 53 To 1 Step -1
    If Dir(csFOLDER_PATH & "SALES BY SKU  STORE wk " & n & "  (retail) (2).xls") <> vbNullString Then
        FileCopy csFOLDER_PATH & "SALES BY SKU  STORE wk " & n & "  (retail) (2).xls", csFOLDER_PATH & "Current BSL, Branch Stock, Whouse Stock, On Order.xls"
        Exit For
    End If
Next n
End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: See https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-an-external-reference-link-to-a-cell-range-in-another-workbook-78344b0c-3458-474d-833e-6d0d55caf96a

Comment: Opening which spreadsheet? The one containing the vlookups (not possible practically, unless you want to go at it with an external program, which efectively opens the file anyway), or the ones being referenced by the vlookups (easy, update links)?

Comment: If I had to make an assumption, the root of your issues sounds like you're trying to create a work around because the VLOOKUPS for future weeks are causing slowdown, since they don't reference existing workbooks. Is that correct? If these wk1.xls, are unchanged after they become available. I'd highly suggest doing a 'one time only' import once the worksheet becomes available, versus a 'VLOOKUP'. VLOOKUP should be used for dynamic data. IMHO, you may be best served creating a macro that opens the workbook and copies the data into the correct 'week' column of cells.

Comment: @ScottCraner I struggle to see how that will help.

Comment: @vacip. It will be the spreadsheet that contains the vlookups.I won't go as far as creating an external program i.e VB application. However, maybe something can be achieved with a PowerShell script that will open and close the spreadsheet. If that will even work.

Comment: @KrisB. I think you may be right. I do have other columns that use vlookups pointing to a static spreadsheet. Within said spreadsheet, there is a macro that will copy and paste an entire workbook everytime a new weekly spreadsheet exists. Suggestively, i could copy a specifiied cell range and paste it into the relevant weekly coloumns. Do you know how to achieve this? Any example code would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use ado to query the workbooks via SQL.https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692882.aspx

Answer (score -2):

If your data is formatted correctly you could achieve the same result without a VLOOKUP and without opening Excel.

The trick is to use an access database and query the spreadsheet by setting it up as a linked table.

Hope this helps.